# Youtube-DL: Is there an output wildcard for which site the video is being downloaded from?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

Youtube-dl supports several sites; in my case I'm using youtube & vimeo. I want to have my '-o' string differentiate between the two when setting an output directory, so that matching users don't clobber each other, and cross-site user's content can be kept separate by site.

I've looked in this list of supported wildcards:

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template

and didn't see one for "site". Are there more wildcards than just the ones in this list? or is that it?

If not, I have some programming experience, how difficult would it be to add the new wildcard myself? I am not familiar with the code at all. Would it be worth investigating? or is there a simpler solution that I'm overlooking?

thanks,
-Yurelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the extractor name as a proxy for site, especially if it's limited to Youtube and Vimeo.

> extractor (string): Name of the extractor

Thus

```
youtube-dl -o '%(extractor)s'
```

with a youtube URL will output to a file named `youtube.mkv` by default. Add other identifiers from the list as you see fit.

[Here's a complete list of extractors](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/tree/master/youtube_dl/extractor), and as you see, major sites have their own specific extractor which will give you information about which site it was downloaded for. The Vimeo extractor is named `vimeo`.

Comment: Awesome! Perfect, thank you.